# How can I use pagination in Woocommerce with a list of known product IDs?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, template, woocommerce

when I click to a **product tag** in woocommerce (example: cats), it goes to the landing page (`mysite.com/product-tag/cats/`) which uses template (`product-archieve.php`), and that template creates a products page with **pagination**.

I have examined contents of `product-archieve.php` but I couldn't figure out how it works, by checking the code.

I have an array of `product ids`, and I want to list my products with same kind of pagination, How can I achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't woocommerce allow you to select how many products to load per page?

In Magento you are able to select how many products to load per page.

Answer (score 0):

Display product categories loop

```
array(
      'number' => 'null',
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'columns' => '20',
      'hide_empty' => '1',
      'parent' => '',
      'ids' => ''
 )
```

The `number` field is used to display the number of products and the `ids` field is to tell the shortcode which categories to display.

```
[product_categories number="12" parent="0"]
```

Set `ids` to a comma separated list of category IDs to only show those.

Comment: this displays all products that belong to a category.  I don't want all products, I have a few products IDs. My use case is this: A user comes, and searchs for a keyword in my website (ex: cat face), so search function returns some product IDs. Now I want to list them in a page with pagination.